# What resources are there for Loop Vectorization (Manual and Automatic) for Visual Studio?

Tags: loops, sse, simd, vectorization

I see some resources for gcc, but not for Visual Studio.

Anyone have a treasure trove of references, examples and tricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think VC++ does loop vectorization.  If you want it, you'll probably have to use [Intel's compiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-with-the-intel-compilers-part-i/). Note that it will plugin to Visual Studio as a drop-in replacement.

Also see this question:

[What compilers besides gcc can vectorize code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409309/what-compilers-besides-gcc-can-vectorize-code)

**UPDATE:** The 2012 version reportedly does auto-vectorization now, see:

[Inside Auto-Vectorization, 1 of n](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization/Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization-1-of-n)

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization is not supported by VC++. But, the SSE support is enabled via intrinsics. Please look this [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/10/18/new-intrinsic-support-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) post.